# Yield and then return or just return?

Tags: python

I have a generator and want to yield none after which I want the iteration of the generator to stop, i.e. `StopIteration` but I am not sure which way to accomplish this.

I think of the following to options:

```
yield None
return
```

and

```
return
```

in my generator.
Are they equivalent? Or which one should I use?

Comment: Remove the return. Keep the yield

Comment: But I want the rest of the code in my generator to be run?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example then?  You can't put stuff after a `return`

Comment: Yes? That is possible.

Comment: When is the "other cool stuff" supposed to run? On the first iteration? Then it should be before `yield None`.

Comment: It is just as an example. Let be alter the example then to make it even more realistic :)

Comment: Well ... what happens when you use each of these methods?  Which one works the way you want?

Comment: They both work. Execution is stopped and `None` is achievable with `yield from`. That is why I wonder if they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

> Are they equivalent?

No.  The second one isn't even a generator (no yield expression)

> Which one should I use?

The first one is fine.  The return statement and also the value `None` explicitly yielded are redundant and can be removed (but they're not harming anything either).

```
def myfunc():
    print("doing stuff before yielding the first (and only) value")
    yield
    print("doing more stuff before raising StopIteration")
```

Should you use an explicit return statement, then the value returned will appear on the `StopIteration` exception instance (literally a `value` attribute).

Syntactically, you *can* put code after the `return` statement, but it will be unreachable. So, there's no point to do that.

Comment: Yea.. My connection went away while editing..

Comment: No, I know what `yield` does and the fact that a `yield` statement makes a function a generator. So in the second case, the code after the `return` would contain a `yield`. Then, what are the difference between `yield None; return` and `return None` or `return` in the case that the function is a generator in BOTH cases

Comment: The difference is whether you yield a value or not.  `list(gen1)` would be `[None]` and `list(gen2)` would be `[]`.

Comment: Even though there were `yield` statements in BOTH cases and thus both are generators?

Comment: Yeah.  Generators can yield no values and still be generators.  I suppose that's kind of a weird maybe use-case for putting a yield statement behind the return, although I don't know why you would want a generator instance which yields no vals as opposed to just passing around a function object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Returning using `return` from a generator doesn't return the value 'None' like a function would. It instead merely stops the generator.

```
>>> def f():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     yield None
...     return
... 
>>> def f2():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     return
... 
>>> for i in f():
...     print(i)
... 
1
2
None
>>> for i in f2():
...     print(i)
... 
1
2
>>>
```